# Return Text with current position Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I want to return some Strings or Texts with :

- name of the city
- postal code
- country

So this is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Maps extends StatefulWidget {
  static Future<void> show(
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Maps(),
        fullscreenDialog: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  _MapsState createState() => _MapsState();
}

Future<Position> locateUser() async {
  return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
}

class _MapsState extends State<Maps> {
  Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator();

  Position _currentPosition;
  String _location;
  String _addressLine;
  bool done = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getCurrentLocation();
    _getLocation(_currentPosition);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                done == false
                    ? Text("Need to get the position")
                    : Text("val 1: $_location, val 2: $_addressLine"),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Get location"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _getCurrentLocation();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _getLocation(Position position) async {
    debugPrint('location: ${position.latitude}');
    final coordinates = new Coordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    List<Address> addresses =
        await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
    Address first = addresses.first;
    _location = "${first.featureName}";
    _addressLine = " ${first.addressLine}";
    done = true;
  }

  void _getCurrentLocation() {
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that it's always returned "Need to get the position" instead of real address.
I know this code isn't the best but it's what comes from hours of researches, I didn't find some clear explanations about the use of geo functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only just made few changes to your code, as i dont want to ruin your code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Maps extends StatefulWidget {
  static Future<void> show(
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Maps(),
        fullscreenDialog: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  _MapsState createState() => _MapsState();
}

Future<Position> locateUser() async {
  return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
}

class _MapsState extends State<Maps> {
  Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator();

  Position _currentPosition;
  String _location;
  String _addressLine;
  bool done = false;

 @override
  void initState() {
    _getCurrentLocation();
  super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                done == false
                    ? Text("Need to get the position")
                    : Text("val 1: $_location, val 2: $_addressLine"),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Get location"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _getCurrentLocation();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _getLocation(Position position) async {
    debugPrint('location: ${position.latitude}');
    final coordinates = new Coordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    List<Address> addresses =
        await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
    Address first = addresses.first;
    _location = "${first.featureName}";
    _addressLine = " ${first.addressLine}";
         setState(() {
              done = true;
          });
 
  }

  void _getCurrentLocation() {
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
    _getLocation(position);
      
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You can change it as much as you want!

Comment: Why did you call the "super.initState" after "_getCurrentLocation" and not before?

Comment: initState is the first thing that execute after the build complete..and _getCurrentLocation is only needed to call once. so i added it into the initState..

Comment: And if the users deny the access to the position how could I ask for the permission again? Because now if the user deny the access I'm not able to ask for it again, if I call "_getCurrentLocation" I have this error "User denied access to the position"